# Static function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning OOP in python and following [this tutorial](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_object_oriented_programming.php). I am confuse about an example which is shown in this article :

```
def f(x):
    f.counter = getattr(f, "counter", 0) + 1 
    return "Monty Python"


for i in range(10):
    f(i)

print(f.counter)
```

I have some doubts.

I know what `getattr(f, "counter", 0)` do. Its give optional values of key to **dict** module.  If an attribute name is not in included in either of the dictionary, the attribute name is not defined.

First i thought `f.counter = getattr(f, "counter", 0) + 1` is doing same work as count do so i replaced `f.counter = getattr(f, "counter", 0) + 1` like this:

```
def f(x):
    count=0
    count+=x
    print(count)

    return "Monty Python"


for i in range(10):
    f(i)


print(count)
```

its working fine but last line `print(count)` is giving error. So my confusion is why count is not global but when i used `f.counter = getattr(f, "counter", 0) + 1` then f.counter was global how??

second question is :

Article says

> "This can be used as a replacement for the static function variables
>   of C and C++, which are not possible in Python."

so what is called static function??

Comment: `count` isn't defined in a global scope, only the scope of `f`. You can't access it outside of `f`. Side note: function attributes are almost never used, and I would question any tutorial that recommends them.

Comment: The article comment should be read as *static function variables*, that is, it is the variables that are static.  In C and C++ there is a qualifier called 'static' which means they have a lifetime of the program unit.  If you don't know C and C++ then its probably best to ignore comments that compare Python with those languages.  Python is WAY more powerful.  Personally I would use a *closure* in Python to achieve the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to note that your function creates a variable `count` every time the function is run, and then once the function exits, `count` disappears. You could also write the function like this:

```
def f():
    f.counter = getattr(f, 'counter', 0) + 1
```

and `f.counter` would still hold the number of times `f` had been executed. We can access `f.counter` because we can access `f`, and nothing is private in Python. If we try to reference `counter` by itself outside the function, it will be a NameError, but only because it looks in every namespace it can find and doesn't see anything named `counter`. You would have to reference `f.counter`

Answer (score 1):

That's because you were assigning a value to an attribute of `f`, which is global. Any changes you make to a global object's attribute is globally visible (even though in this case your global object is a function and it's not usual to work with attributes in function). When you made your changes, you created a `count` variable inside your function's scope, thus not being accessible outside of it.